# Regex - Repleace "//" with " "

Tags: php, regex

Some trouble with an RegEx for PhoneNumbers, it works so far but i cant figure out how to Repleace "//" with Spaces:

Input: 0()()()111 1-11**//**1111

**Expected**:: +49 111 111 1111

**Got**: +49 111 1111111

```
$pattern = array(
            '/[^0-9\+\.\-\(\) ]/',   // Cut all characters that are not allowed
            '/^00/',                 // Start with 00 ist changed to +
            '/^(0)(\d)/',            // Start with 0[1-9] ist changed to +49 [0-9]
            '/[\.\-\(\)]/',          // Change allowed characters to ' '
            '/\s[\s]+/',             // Change grouped spaces too one
            '/((\+49 )(0))(.*)/'
        );

$change = array('', '+', '+49 $2', ' ', ' ', '$2$4');
$value = preg_replace($pattern, $change, $value);
```

Added Chars to:

```
 '/[\.\-\(\)]/',          // Change allowed characters to ' '
```

wich does not work. Sorry my knowledge about Regex is limited.

Comment: I may not be seeing it, but where do you attempt to replace `//`?  Is there a reason you can't just escape it?

Comment: You are removing every non matching character first `'/[^0-9\+\.\-\(\) ]/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, I've just tested it and works. So first I'm going to replace the double slash and then the characters that are not allowed.

```
$pattern = array(
            '/[\/]{2}/',             // Replacing //
            '/[^0-9\+\.\-\(\) ]/',   // Cut all characters that are not allowed
            '/^00/',                 // Start with 00 ist changed to +
            '/^(0)(\d)/',            // Start with 0[1-9] ist changed to +49 [0-9]
            '/[\.\-\(\)]/',          // Change allowed characters to ' '
            '/\s[\s]+/',             // Change grouped spaces too one
            '/((\+49 )(0))(.*)/'
        );

$change = array(' ', '', '+', '+49 $2', ' ', ' ', '$2$4');
$value = preg_replace($pattern, $change, $value);
```

Answer (score 1):

i cant find the pattern that replaces the `*//*` to space!, there are two patter that replaces with space the 3rd and 4th, where the 3rd `'/[\.\-\(\)]/'` this only targets the following chars `.-()` and the 4th as you said its for white spaces.

another point the first pattern is removing them before the others sees them because the `*` and the `/` and not allowed chars in your list,

so after the first pattern you'll have the following string `0()()()111 1-111111`
and it will continue to execute the other patterns.